# IOS Broadcast Framework

Tags: ios, streaming, broadcast, rtmp, broadcasting

Can someone point me in the right direction to find the tools to be able to build a really simple broadcasting app on ios.

I am looking to mimic what has been done [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-broadcaster/id632458541?mt=8).

Been googling around for a while now and can't really find anything to get me started.

Found this:
http://olobonsoft.com/products

Can anyone help or tried to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Never try but I know this project (for cine.io) on Github, check source code of project, probably will be not different that what you're looking for.

Example app : https://github.com/cine-io/cineio-broadcast-ios-example-app

> Sample iOS application to demonstrate broadcasting and playback using
>   the cine.io Broadcast iOS SDK.
>
> How to Use
>
> Clone the repository. Create a cineio-settings.plist file based on the
>   SAMPLE-cineio- settings.plist file. You'll need to create a (free)
>   account at cine.io. Change into the Example directory: cd Example
>   Install the necessary CocoaPods: pod install Build and run the project
>   as you usually would, making sure to use the .xcworkspace file and not
>   the .xcproject file when building using xcodebuild or when opening
>   with Xcode.

project : https://github.com/cine-io/cineio-broadcast-ios